# posts going to 2 pages/categories only show up in 1

Tags: posts, categories, loop, pages

I have a portfolio website where my portfolio updates are supposed to go to both my [portfolio](http://frshstudio.com/work) and [blog](http://frshstudio.com/blog) pages, as well as show thumbnails for the posts on my [homepage](http://frshstudio.com).

The thumbnails work perfectly; if a post is to go in two categories, the thumbnails show up in both categories.

My trouble is with the blog- posts marked to go in both blog and portfolio categories only show up in my portfolio. Here's what I'm using for the blog:

```
<div id="blog">
    <?php query_posts('cat=-4'); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post('cat=-3,4'); ?>
    <div class="post-title">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div><!-- end post-title -->
    <div class="post">
        <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
    </div><!-- end post -->
    <div class="post-meta">
        <p><?php the_date(); ?> | <?php the_tags('tags:', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p>
    </div><!-- end post-meta -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
            <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end blog -->
```

Any ideas what could be causing this or how to remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing : you should not use category ids directly. Use [slugs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) instead : it's easier to maintain.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=portfolio'); ?>
```

Second thing : why did you put a query parameter in `the_post` ? This function does not accept any parameter ([see the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)).

Third thing : the call to `query_posts('cat=-4');` will show all posts EXCEPT the one that have the category N°4 (portfolio, if [I guess well](http://frshstudio.com/?cat=4)). This is not want you want, right ?

Want you want is `query_posts('category_name=portfolio');` in your portfolio page and `query_posts('category_name=blog');` in your blog page.